# No module named linq Error only when job is using python

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I have a table in sql database which I inserted a python code as data.
I wanna map an entity to another one (first one is mine and the second one is from web service). So I used python for mapping. I used this python code in two places and in both of them it just maps the entities. the first place used in Job Service and works Parallel and the Second place is for mapping and show mapped Entity in XML Format.
the problem is when the job is mapping entities, the python says No module named linq!
but when I want to see the mapped entity, it maps and the xml show the mapped entity without any problems. whats wrong? the code is the same but somewhere I get error.
here is some part of my python script. Any opinion?

```
import System
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference(''System.Core'')
clr.AddReference(''Tools.Cmn'')
clr.AddReference(''Tools.ThinCmn'')
clr.AddReference(''Common.Cmn'')
clr.AddReference(''Common.SA'')
clr.AddReference(''Life.SA'')
clr.AddReference(''Life.Cmn'')
clr.AddReference(''Life.BL'')
from Tools.Cmn import *
from Common.Cmn import *
from Common.SA import *
from Life.Cmn import *
from Life.BL import *
from Life.SA.CiiRegLifePlcyServices import *
from Life.SA import *
from System import Array
from System import DateTime
from System import Func
from System.Linq import Enumerable
from System.Collections.Generic import *
StrTools = StringToolsExposeToScript()
CIHelper = LifeCIWebServiceHelper()
########################################
def Map(bnVer , lifPlcyReq, extraInfo):
    isEdm = 0 if bnVer.ElhNo == 0 else 1
    isPrps = extraInfo["IsPrps"]
    try :
        calcList = bnVer.LifePolicyCalcGeneralList.LoadAll()            
            for calc in calcList:
                clc = System.Activator.CreateInstance(LifPlcyYrReq)
                clc.YrNo = calc.Year
                clc.PayCnt = calc.InstallmentCnt            
                clc.Svng = calc.PrmReserved
                clc.GrntPrftRte = calc.PolicyYearInterest
                clc.CfcChngPrm = calc.PolicyYearPrmChangeZarib      
                LifPlcyYrLst.Add(clc)           
        lifPlcyReq.LifPlcyYrLst = LifPlcyYrLst.ToArray()
                            
    except TypeError, err:
        raise Exception(str(err) + " line : " + str(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
    except:
        raise       
    return
```

Comment: You've posted nearly 200 lines of code, but not *the full error message with stack trace*. That makes it very difficult to find where the error is. You say the error is *somewhere* but the stack trace is telling you exactly where it is. You need to share that information with us if we are to be able to help.

Comment: actually I'm using Iron python and that's All I have. system just says No module named linq and for inner exception I have only the Method which uses Iron python and its not traceable. and this method works fine when I call it from UI To create XML of Mapped Entity.

Comment: If you cut your code down to `import System;from System.Linq import Enumerable` do  you get the same error?

Comment: No. there is nothing in code to cause this error. I think maybe its an Iron python issue. It goes sometimes and comeback another time without any reason. for example now I'm running my job and error occurs but when I try 30 minutes later it runs successfully for the exact same test case, without any change in code.